# Swift -How to performBatchUpdates on a collectionView with multiple sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView that has has 3 sections each with a different cell (it was easier to separate the cell's data into separate sections than just 1 section).

There is only 1 dataModel inside the collectionView's data source, it gets updated but **I only need that update to show in the first section** (a new label gets added). When I try to run `collectionView.performBatchUpdates` the entire layout gets messed up and it goes from showing all 3 sections to only showing the last section with the first 2 completely gone. It's not the constraints because when I pop off and push back on the layout is perfect with the new label that shows the updated data in the first section and the other 2 appear fine. The problem seems to occur in when I run perform batchUpdates

I tried:

```
let updatedDataModel = ...

guard let indexOfItem = tableData.firstIndex(where: { $0.itemId == updatedDataModel.itemId }) else { return }

tableData[indexOfItem] = updatedDataModel

let indexPath = IndexPath(item: indexOfItem, section: 0)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0) {

    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in

        self?.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        self?.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (_) in
        print("success")
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 0)
    self.collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
}, completion: nil)
```

I tried:

```
let updatedDataModel = ...

guard let indexOfItem = tableData.firstIndex(where: { $0.itemId == updatedDataModel.itemId }) else { return }

tableData[indexOfItem] = updatedDataModel

let indexPath0 = IndexPath(item: indexOfItem, section: 0)
let indexPath1 = IndexPath(item: indexOfItem, section: 1)
let indexPath2 = IndexPath(item: indexOfItem, section: 2)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0) {

    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ [weak self] in

        self?.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath0, indexPath1, indexPath2])
        self?.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }) { (_) in
        print("success")
    }
}
```

cellForItem:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // *** this section is where the updated data (an additional label) needs to appear
    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: topCell, for: indexPath) as! TopCell
        cell.dataModel = tableData[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: middleCell, for: indexPath) as! MiddleCell
        cell.dataModel = tableData[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    if indexPath.section == 2 {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: bottomCell, for: indexPath) as! BottomCell
        cell.dataModel = tableData[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    // if for some reason something goes wrong above but this NEVER runs
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: errorCell, for: indexPath) as! ErrorCell
    return errorCell
}
```

dataSource:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return 1
    }

    if section == 1 {
        return tableData.count
    }

    if section == 2 {
        return 1
    }

    return 0
}
```

Where am I going wrong at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `collectionView.performBatchUpdates` and instead just write the following to reload data only in the section you want:

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 0)       // Change integer to whatever section you want to reload
collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
```

And if you do not want any animations for this `UICollectionView` reload use:

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    // same code as above
}
```

---

Good luck.

Comment: I'll post numberOfSections and numberOfItems, the size for item has way to many things going on for it for each section, it won;t be readable.

Comment: I added it at the bottom of the question

Comment: I think you might have just helped me figure out what's causing the issue. Gimme a few minutes I'm trying it now.

Comment: @LanceSamaria everything seems fine, have you tried logging (printing to console) some random value and see if sections are reloaded in `cellForItemAt` method?

Comment: @LanceSamaria there also might be some issues with item sizing for section, but as you said, you don't want to post it because code is messy, check if it is ok.

Comment: The sizeForItem works fine because when I push off and back on the layout is as its supposed to be. I think the problem is happening somewhere else, and that's causing the issue. I'm trying to locate it now. If I find I 'm going to run it with code from your original answer and when if it works, I'll accept it. Gimme like 15 min while I try to locate this bug. Thanks for the suggestions too, they definitely helped!

Comment: I found the bug, for some reason when I updated the dataModel inside *tableData[indexOfItem] = updatedDataModel* this was causing some issue, all I did was update the properties instead of the entire model itself and it fixed. I used it with the code from your answer and it worked fine. Thanks for help, cheers! :)

Comment: Quick question, why not use performBatchUpdates? In my other vcs, if I have to update a cell in where the entire cv has only 1 section everything works fine when I use it. I found out what was causing the bug but if you have the time you should add an explanation to your answer on why not to use it or better yet what's the difference between the using it and not using

Comment: @LanceSamaria `performBatchUpdates` is used for animating insert, deletes, reloads and movement of data in cells, thus it is not necessary as `.reloadSections`, in my experience, usually does animate changes as well, not always tho. So I just thought that it might cause some animation issues as well as displaying the cells correctly.